# can not use FieldCache on multivalued field in Solr 3.1

Tags: solr

When I migrate from Solr 1.4 to solr 3.1 , some errors occurred 
I used sort on a text field which works in solr 1.4 to sort on this field 
and in solr 1.4 I used an integer field in bf parameter but not worked in solr 3.1 with error message :  can not use FieldCache on multivalued field

I need hellp to solve this problem especially I have to use this fields to boost my results

Comment: I think Ii now works , just add multivalue="false" in schema.xml for fields that doesn't allow FiedlCache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have these fields in your schema.xml as you should make sure they are set to multiValued=false

```
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: I think not only for dynamic fields , but also fr all fields that you should make multivalued=false